# Match second number, if the first doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a regex that needs to remove data that is in a large text. Before running the regex, I replace all spaces, all lines by a single space, so a spreadsheet like this:

```
Something    50.00  10.00
Other Piece        100,00
```

Becomes this:

```
Something 50.00  10.00 Other Piece 100,00
```

This table in specific, there is 4 columns , number, name, amount of fees and the total amount, this way:

```
01 Some Name  40,000  10.000
02 Some Name  40,000  10.000
03 Some Name  40,000  10.000
```

But sometimes, the amount of fees doesn't exist, just the total amount:

01 Some Name          10.000
01 Some Name  40,000  10.000

And i just need catch the total amount, so i'm suffering to find out a regex to catch the 4 value, if the 3 value exists.

That's how long i get:

```
\b(?:228)\s.*?(?:[a-z]+)\s(?:[\d/.,]+)?\s([\d/.,]+)
```

This RegExp is capturing the 4 number if the 3 exists, but when the 3 doesn't exist, it won't work. So, i would like to ask for help. How can i make this work?

What i'm trying to do is:

Find a number defined by me, like 228, after that, find the name, which can be one or more, after, catch the 2 value if the 1 value exists, or catch the 1 value if the second doesn't exist.

http://regexr.com/3cq7e

Thanks!!!

Update -

Also, i can't change the process before, so i can't avoid removing the lines, spaces, etc. And i can't use a regex like: find the number defined by me, after that find the name, then find the next name and catch the previous value, cause sometimes the next name may not exists.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use [`[\d.,]+$`](http://regexr.com/3cq7h) with `gm` flags before removing the spaces and linebreaks.

Comment: Unfortunate this isn't a option, i can't remove the first process, i don't have access.

Comment: Can we rephrase your problem to `match always last number` ?

Comment: @Celu: Did the regex I posted below work?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
\b(?:228)\s+(?:[A-Za-z ]+?)\s+(?:[\d]+[.,][\d]+\s+)?([\d]+[.,][\d]+)
```

This assumes that the names have no special characters or numbers (that they have only A through Z or white space).  Another assumption is that the amount of fees and total amount always have either a period or comma and also have digits following the period or comma.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a regex that supports multiline and search always for the **last** decimal number ? This way you will get either the 4th or the 3rd numbers, whatever exists.

```
(\d+\.?\d+)$/gm
```

[image]

Play with it [here](http://regexr.com/3cq9d).